# Content is not allowed in prolog error while parsing json using xslt 3.0

Tags: json, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am trying to do one POC to transform json to xml format. Now i am doing it via java using Saxon-HE version 9.8.0-5

Let's assume a simple json as :

```
{
  "Assets": [
    { "Asset": {
      "Open": "25.15",
      "High": "25.15",
      "Low": "25.11",
      "Close": "25.87"
    }},
    { "Asset": {
      "Open": "25.15",
      "High": "25.15",
      "Low": "25.11",
      "Close": "25.87"
    }}
  ]
}
```

Now the java code is as below:

```
public void transform(File xsl, File inputjson, File outputXml) throws TransformerException, IOException {
        TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(xsl);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        System.out.println("transformer object created");
        Source text = new StreamSource(inputjson);
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(outputXml));
    }
```

But I get below error:

> Error on line 1 column 1 of sample_test1.json:
>   SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog.

When I tried to put the json content within any xml element and process it, it was successful. WHY??
Can we not directly process a json as is without putting it's content into any xml structure?

Comment: You are using an API defined for XSLT 1 which takes XML input and not JSON. If you switch to the Saxon s9api you can start with a named template and the JSON as a text parameter or an XPath map parameter or even use an XdmValue for the template match, http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#applyTemplates-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue-net.sf.saxon.s9api.Destination-

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen for your response. I tried using s9api as well. But it seems working for xml as input only and when i use for json input it is giving the same error. I followed the test cases written by saxon. I guess i am making some mistake while using s9api for json parsing. Can you please share some example or code snippet for direct json parsing using saxon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to share the code of the XSLT you have respectively the way you want to process JSON first. What exactly do you want to do with the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are probably using an XML parser to parse JSON input. It's not clear whether the variable "inputjson" holds the actual JSON text, or the URI of a file containing the actual JSON text, but either way, it isn't going to work.

Because template rules aren't very usable on anything except XML nodes (despite the fact that XSLT 3.0 actually allows them), I would tend to write this transformation like this:

```
<xsl:param name="json-uri"/>
<xsl:initial-template name="main">
  <xsl:variable name="parsed-json" select="json-doc($json-uri)"/>
  ....
</xsl:initial-template>
```

(That's assuming you start with the URI of a file holding the JSON)

and then invoke it using s9api code along the lines of

```
Xslt30Transformer trans = ...;
Map<QName, XdmValue> params = new HashMap<>();
params.add(new QName("", "json-uri"), new XdmAtomicValue(jsonInputUri));
trans.setStylesheetParameters(params);
trans.callTemplate(new QName("", "main"), serializer);
```